# How to find the number of values in a given range divisible by a given value?

Tags: algorithm, math

I have three numbers x, y , z.

For a range between numbers x and y.

How can i find the total numbers whose % with z is 0 i.e. how many numbers between x and y are divisible by z ?

Comment: If it's a homework, perhaps the plain old boring and slow "try each and count" will do.

Comment: no, not a homework.... i need it for some optimization.

Comment: If it's not a homework, remove the C and C++ tags, add an algorithm tag and perhaps do some thinking (hint: find the first one in O(1), find the last one in O(1), find the count of all other in O(1))

Comment: `|x - y| / z` = `|10 - 2| / 3` or `|100 - 10| / 5` or ...?

Comment: @Rubens that won't do. There are three even numbers in `[1..5]`, but only two in `[2..6]`

Comment: +1 because I want [Hobbs' solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16382016/499214) get reviewed and outscore mine if correct ;-) and because this question is general enough to deserve an optimal solution

Comment: Found the same problem in JetBrains Academy https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2743  This seems to take care of it: System.out.print(b / n - a / n + a % n == 0 ? 1 : 0);  x->a, y->b, z->n

Comment: when facing a range [n...m] you should floor(m/z) - floor((n-1)/z)

Answer (score 32):

It can be done in O(1): find the first one, find the last one, find the count of all other.

I'm assuming the range is inclusive. If your ranges are exclusive, adjust the bounds by one:

- find the first value after `x` that is divisible by `z`. You can discard `x`:

  ```
  x_mod = x % z;

  if(x_mod != 0)
    x += (z - x_mod);
  ```
- find the last value before `y` that is divisible by `y`. You can discard `y`:

  ```
  y -= y % z;
  ```
- find the size of this range:

  ```
  if(x > y)
    return 0;
  else
    return (y - x) / z + 1;
  ```

If mathematical `floor` and `ceil` functions are available, the first two parts can be written more readably. Also the last part can be compressed using math functions:

```
 x = ceil  (x, z);
 y = floor (y, z);
 return max((y - x) / z + 1, 0);
```

if the input is guaranteed to be a valid range (`x >= y`), the last test or `max` is unneccessary:

```
 x = ceil  (x, z);
 y = floor (y, z);
 return (y - x) / z + 1;
```

Comment: @OpMt y and x are both divisible by z, so (y-x)/2 is just the number of z that fit between x and y. Add 1 to account for endpoint x since the [x,y] range is inclusive. Example: numbers divisible by 2 in [0,4] are (0,2,4) so 4/2=2 and 2+1=3 (three numbers are divisible). Another example: numbers divisible by 2 in [0,0] are (0) so 0/2+1=1 (one number is divisible).

Answer (score 24):

<sup>(*2017, answer rewritten thanks to comments*)</sup>
The number of multiples of *z* in a number *n* is simply `n / z`

`/` being the integer division, meaning decimals that could result from the division are simply ignored (for instance `17/5 => 3` and not `3.4`).

Now, in a range from *x* to *y*, how many multiples of *z* are there?

Let see how many multiples *m* we have up to *y*

```
0----------------------------------x------------------------y
-m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---m---
```

You see where I'm going... to get the number of multiples in the range `[ x, y ]`, get the number of multiples of *y* then subtract the number of multiples before *x*, `(x-1) / z`

Solution: `( y / z ) - (( x - 1 ) / z )`

---

Programmatically, you could make a function `numberOfMultiples`

```
function numberOfMultiples(n, z) {
   return n / z;
}
```

to get the number of multiples in a range `[x, y]`

```
numberOfMultiples(y) - numberOfMultiples(x-1)
```

The function is *O(1)*, there is no need of a loop to get the number of multiples.

Examples of results you should find

- `[30, 90] ÷ 13 => 4`
- `[1, 1000] ÷ 6 => 166`
- `[100, 1000000] ÷ 7 => 142843`
- `[777, 777777777] ÷ 7 => 111111001`

For the first example, `90 / 13 = 6`, `(30-1) / 13 = 2`, and `6-2 = 4`

```
---26---39---52---65---78---91--
     ^                      ^
     30<---(4 multiples)-->90
```

Comment: I don't understand "function f to calculate the number of multiples for any number n". Do you mean integer division?

Comment: Yes, *(integer division)* is written below the *multiples* line

Comment: The solution is very good but the answer's text is messy. You definitely could improve it to make it great. Maybe adding some examples:
`x = 6, y = 11, z = 2 {
11 / 2 = 5        => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
(6 - 1) / 2 = 2  => [2, 4]
Answer is 3    => [6, 8, 10] }`

Answer (score 18):

I also encountered this on Codility. It took me much longer than I'd like to admit to come up with a good solution, so I figured I would share what I think is an elegant solution!

### Straightforward Approach 1/2:

O(N) time solution with a loop and counter, unrealistic when N = 2 billion.

### Awesome Approach 3:

We want the number of digits in some range that are divisible by K.

Simple case: assume range [0 .. n*K], N = n*K

> N/K represents the number of digits in [0,N) that are divisible by K, given N%K = 0 (aka. N is divisible by K)

ex. N = 9, K = 3, Num digits = |{0 3 6}| = 3 = 9/3

Similarly,

> N/K + 1 represents the number of digits in [0,N] divisible by K

ex. N = 9, K = 3, Num digits = |{0 3 6 9}| = 4 = 9/3 + 1

I think really understanding the above fact is the trickiest part of this question, I cannot explain exactly why it works.
  The rest boils down to *prefix sums* and *handling special cases*.

---

Now we don't always have a range that begins with 0, and we cannot assume the two bounds will be divisible by K.
  But wait! We can fix this by calculating our own nice upper and lower bounds and using some subtraction magic :)

1. First find the closest upper and lower in the range [A,B] that are divisible by K.

   - Upper bound (easier): ex. B = 10, K = 3, new_B = 9... the pattern is B - B%K
   - Lower bound: ex. A = 10, K = 3, new_A = 12... try a few more and you will see the pattern  is A - A%K + K
2. Then calculate the following using the above technique:

   - Determine the total number of digits X between [0,B] that are divisible by K
   - Determine the total number of digits Y between [0,A) that are divisible by K
3. Calculate the number of digits between [A,B] that are divisible by K in constant time by the expression X - Y

Website: https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/count_div/

```
class CountDiv {
    public int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
        int firstDivisible = A%K == 0 ? A : A + (K - A%K);
        int lastDivisible = B%K == 0 ? B : B - B%K; //B/K behaves this way by default.
        return (lastDivisible - firstDivisible)/K + 1;
    }
}
```

This is my first time explaining an approach like this. Feedback is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 12):

This is one of the Codility Lesson 3 questions. For this question, the input is guaranteed to be in a valid range. I answered it using Javascript:

```
function solution(x, y, z) {
    var totalDivisibles =  Math.floor(y / z),
        excludeDivisibles = Math.floor((x - 1) / z),
        divisiblesInArray = totalDivisibles - excludeDivisibles;
   return divisiblesInArray;
}
```

https://codility.com/demo/results/demoQX3MJC-8AP/

(I actually wanted to ask about some of the other comments on this page but I don't have enough rep points yet).

Comment: This one is briliant!!! Clever and simple. It is so simple that most of people including me did not come up with it. Great but no "Math.floor" is needed.

Answer (score 5):

Divide `y-x` by `z`, rounding down. Add one if `y%z < x%z` or if `x%z == 0`.

No mathematical proof, unless someone cares to provide one, but test cases, in Perl:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

sub multiples_in_range {
  my ($x, $y, $z) = @_;
  return 0 if $x > $y;
  my $ret = int( ($y - $x) / $z);
  $ret++ if $y%$z < $x%$z or $x%$z == 0;
  return $ret;
}   

for my $z (2 .. 10) {
  for my $x (0 .. 2*$z) {
    for my $y (0 .. 4*$z) {
      is multiples_in_range($x, $y, $z),
         scalar(grep { $_ % $z == 0 } $x..$y),
         "[$x..$y] mod $z";
    }
  }
}

done_testing;
```

Output:

```
$ prove divrange.pl 
divrange.pl .. ok      
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=3405,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.20 usr  0.02 sys +  0.26 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.49 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Comment: Seems correct (and would be the best answer), but you'll need to convince me you're not off-by-one ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think I'm up to proving it at 2:30 AM, but it seems to work quite well (after my edit).

Comment: @hobbs throw in your test cases, then :-) (and a disclaimer)

Comment: I guess `is` is a multi-way equals for unit tests? Also, why do I find `grep { $_ % $z == 0 } $x..$y` much less readable than, say, `[$x..$y].filter{|$x| $x % $z == 0}` (ruby) or `[$x..$y].filter ($x) => $x % $z == 0` (coffeescript)?

Comment: @JanDvorak it's a testing thing, yes. The syntax is `is $test_value, $expected, $description`. As for the latter, it's just what you're used to. I find the coffeescript one near-impossible to scan.

Comment: @hobbs what if I add parentheses around the condition block (lambda)?

Answer (score 5):

Let `[A;B]` be an interval of positive integers including **A** and **B** such that `0 <= A <= B`, **K** be the divisor.

It is easy to see that there are `N(A) = ⌊A / K⌋ = floor(A / K)` factors of **K** in interval `[0;A]`:

```
         1K       2K       3K       4K       5K
●········x········x··●·····x········x········x···>
0                    A
```

Similarly, there are `N(B) = ⌊B / K⌋ = floor(B / K)` factors of **K** in interval `[0;B]`:

```
         1K       2K       3K       4K       5K
●········x········x········x········x···●····x···>
0                                       B
```

Then `N = N(B) - N(A)` equals to the number of **K**'s (the number of integers divisible by **K**) in range `(A;B]`. The point ***A*** is not included, because the *subtracted `N(A)` includes this point*. Therefore, the result should be incremented by one, if `A mod K` is zero:

```
N := N(B) - N(A)

if (A mod K = 0)
  N := N + 1
```

**Implementation in PHP**

```
function solution($A, $B, $K) {
  if ($K < 1)
    return 0;

  $c = floor($B / $K) - floor($A / $K);

  if ($A % $K == 0)
    $c++;

  return (int)$c;
}
```

In PHP, the effect of the `floor` function can be achieved by casting to the integer type:

```
$c = (int)($B / $K) - (int)($A / $K);
```

which, I think, is faster.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my short and simple solution in C++ which got 100/100 on codility. :)
Runs in O(1) time. I hope its not difficult to understand.

```
int solution(int A, int B, int K) {
    // write your code in C++11
    int cnt=0;
    if( A%K==0 or B%K==0)
        cnt++;
    if(A>=K)
        cnt+= (B - A)/K;
    else
        cnt+=B/K;

    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(floor)(high/d) - (floor)(low/d) - (high%d==0)
```

**Explanation:**

There are a/d numbers divisible by d from 0.0 to a. (d!=0)

Therefore (floor)(high/d) - (floor)(low/d) will give numbers divisible in the range (low,high] (Note that low is excluded and high is included in this range)

Now to remove high from the range just subtract (high%d==0)

Works for integers, floats or whatever (Use fmodf function for floats)

Answer (score 0):

Won't strive for an o(1) solution, this leave for more clever person:) Just feel this is a perfect usage scenario for function programming. Simple and straightforward.

```
 > x,y,z=1,1000,6
 => [1, 1000, 6] 
 > (x..y).select {|n| n%z==0}.size
 => 166
```

EDIT: after reading other's O(1) solution. I feel shamed. Programming made people lazy to think...

Comment: ungh. Possibly great for code golf but terribly slow ;-) However, it's not very readable for someone without the knowledge of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Division (a/b=c) by definition - taking a set of size a and forming groups of size b. The number of groups of this size that can be formed, c, is the quotient of a and b. - is nothing more than the number of integers within range/interval ]0..a] (not including zero, but including a) that are divisible by b.

so by definition: 
Y/Z - number of integers within ]0..Y] that are divisible by Z
and
X/Z - number of integers within ]0..X] that are divisible by Z

thus:
result = [Y/Z] - [X/Z] + x (where x = 1 if and only if X is divisible by Y otherwise 0 - assuming the given range [X..Y] includes X)

example :
for (6, 12, 2) we have 12/2 - 6/2 + 1 (as 6%2 == 0) = 6 - 3 + 1 = 4 // {6, 8, 10, 12}
for (5, 12, 2) we have 12/2 - 5/2 + 0 (as 5%2 != 0) = 6 - 2 + 0 = 4 // {6, 8, 10, 12}

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the solution  will be linear.

### Code Snippet :

```
int countDiv(int a, int b, int m)
{
    int mod = (min(a, b)%m==0);
    int cnt  = abs(floor(b/m) - floor(a/m))  +  mod;
    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here n will give you count of number and will print sum of all numbers that are divisible by `k`

```
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
int k = sc.nextInt();
int first = 0;

if (a > k) {
  first = a + a/k;
} else {
  first = k;
}

int last = b - b%k;

if (first > last) {
  System.out.println(0);
} else {
  int n = (last - first)/k+1;
  System.out.println(n * (first + last)/2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the problem written in **Swift Programming Language**.

**Step 1:** Find the first number in the range divisible by z.

**Step 2:** Find the last number in the range divisible by z.

**Step 3:** Use a mathematical formula to find the number of divisible numbers by z in the range.

```
func solution(_ x : Int, _ y : Int, _ z : Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfDivisible = 0

    var firstNumber: Int
    var lastNumber: Int

    if y == x {
        return x % z == 0 ? 1 : 0
    }
    
    //Find first number divisible by z
    let moduloX = x % z

    if moduloX == 0 {
        firstNumber = x
    } else {
        firstNumber = x + (z - moduloX)
    }

    //Fist last number divisible by z
    let moduloY = y % z
    if moduloY == 0 {
        lastNumber = y
    } else {
        lastNumber = y - moduloY
    }

    //Math formula
    numberOfDivisible = Int(floor(Double((lastNumber - firstNumber) / z))) + 1

    return numberOfDivisible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static int Solution(int A, int B, int K)
{

```
        int count = 0;

        //If A is divisible by K
        if(A % K == 0)
        {
            count = (B / K) - (A / K) + 1;
        }
        //If A is not divisible by K
        else if(A % K != 0)
        {
            count = (B / K) - (A / K);
        }

        return count;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in O(1).
Here you are a solution in C++.

```
auto first{ x % z == 0 ? x : x + z - x % z };
auto last{ y % z == 0 ? y : y - y % z };
auto ans{ (last - first) / z + 1 };
```

Where first is the first number that ∈ [x; y] and is divisible by z, last is the last number that ∈ [x; y] and is divisible by z and ans is the answer that you are looking for.